# How to I make the water in my FLIP Fluid simulation roll off the sides of my sub?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

How do I prevent the water on the sub from splashing upwards and instead roll off the sides of the sub?

I have included an image of right before everything goes wrong, what I want is for the water to roll off the sides of the animated submarine and fall back down. Instead what is actually happening is the sub raises into the air and the water acts like it's getting shoveled up, exploding up into the air. Now I have tried various work arounds to get a similar effect (like animated textures and using particles, etc.) However this is the closest I have gotten to the effect I want.

I have been working on getting the fluid in this simulation looking right for about a few weeks. However I keep running into the same issue over and over again. I've managed to make the water look realistic by cranking the resolution up to 600, I've followed tutorials online on how to make the water splash realistic by setting surface tension to Base 0.02 (90% accuracy) and enabling sheeting effects with 0.5 sheeting strength and 0.1 sheeting thickness. Which those have succeeded in making the water look right and react correctly, but nothing I have done has fixed this one glaring issue.

I am using the demo version of the FLIP fluids addon if that makes any difference, but honestly I don't think it would make a difference.

To summarize what I want to happen: I want the submarine to rise out the water, the water should fall off the sub after rising with it, the sub rises above the water and it will fly offscreen.

The problem I want to fix: The water continues to rise up instead of falling off the sub.

To be clear the first image is right before the water should start falling off the sub, the last image is the effect that keeps happening at it's most extreme, at it's least extremes it just keeps rising up and hits the ceiling when it shouldn't even come close to the top of the domain.

The 4th image shows my problem that still persists.

This edit is just to clarify some details  might not have explained correctly. The Sub is an imported object that is being controlled by a Null object which is using cached data to tell the submarine how to move and where to go. I cannot edit it or make it move at a realistic rate. So I need to know how to make the fluid move in a way that would compensate for the unrealistic speed of the, allowing the fluid to roll off the sides around frame 25.

[image: Right before everything explodes.]

[image: Settings Screenshot]

[image: Timeline Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Please show some of your settings as a Blender screen capture.  I think your question would be easier to read if you put the actual question at the top.   Consider changing your time frame and size of animation.  Moving a marble of glass  through liquid is different than  moving a beach ball.  Viscosity can be inspected as well.

Comment: Ok as a follow-up question how do I share some settings as a Blender screen capture? Also I'll edited it to have the question closer to the top. I actually have set the animation to the smallest settings it can be, at least without editing the sub. The whole scene was imported to be used in a larger project, I just need to make the fluid effect work with the scene that I've been given.

Comment: Your edit is a big improvement. You have a screen capture of a submarine.  Please show the FS Fluid Simulation settings as a screen capture.  I realize you have some of the settings as text.  I think they would be easier to understand as a screen capture.

Comment: I have added pictures of what you requested, I'm not sure if I'm getting things exactly right in what you want but I have provided more images and changed the edits. I tried working with viscosity before but I don't want this to end up looking like honey or a thick fluid. When I was baking this at a about a 150 resolution I kept getting told that it didn't look realistic, specifically because it looked too globby, so I upped the resolution to 600.  Now I'm not too sure what you mean by FS Fluid simulation settings, but I did include the settings I stated. If you need anything more let me know.

Comment: What is your time frame?  What happens if an experiment is performed and you take twice as much time?  Time might be a setting in your Fluid Simulation (FS).  I do realize FS experiments demand computer resources and time.

Comment: The time frame? It's between frame 0 and frame 101. If that's not the answer you want then how do I go about finding where the time setting may be?

Comment: Blender FS has a time setting, independent of frames rendered.  The time setting produces different outcomes. You are using something different.  As an alternative ... If you change your time of submarine motion to 200 frames then your velocity is less and water splash would be less.

Comment: As a secondary inquiry does your tool crash all the time?   .. a la mode of Blender FS.

Comment: Ok so if I were to make the timeline longer in the FLIP Fluids settings then hypothetically speaking the fluid would react differently? I'll crank down my resolution and give this a test bake to see if it works.

Comment: Also yes, it actually does crash a good bit but only at high resolutions. This tool is actually designed specifically for liquids as opposed to Blender's all purpose fluid system.

Comment: If Flip Fluids has a time setting yes that would change the outcome.  I assume it does.  You have not shown the setting or stated its absence.   It could be misleading to turn down resolution for reasons you probably know.  I clearly am  not using Flip Fluids.

Comment: Well I cannot state it's presence if I don't know if it's there, I can't state it's absence if it's inconclusive whether or not it has one. I would send a screenshot but I can't find that setting. Now I do know that cranking down the resolution can be misleading, but I don't exactly have up to 19 hours to let this thing bake half way. I just need to see if this causes things to change as you stated.

Comment: You may have seen this already. https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Domain-Advanced-Settings#simulation-stability  .. the sentence starting ... Tip: for large scale simulations, such as oceans, beaches, or other slow moving bodies of water, you can often get away with a higher CFL number such as 10 or 15 without affecting results.

Comment: I don't think FLIP Fluids has a setting like that

Comment: Hi, I would not recommend enabling surface tension or sheeting effects (or viscosity as well) for this type of effect. These features or more for small-scale liquids and can cause problems like this in a large-scale effect. Sheeting is also a specialized feature that may not be suitable for all effects and can lead to this problem. See the sheeting notes here: https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Domain-World-Settings#sheeting-effects

Mostly default settings should be fine for large-scale effects assuming correct world scale and realistic speeds of objects.

Comment: That's the thing, the sub is animated and moving at an unrealistic speed. Aside from that I'll try disabling the sheeting and surface tension in my next bake.

Comment: I also really want the fluid to separate and appear like realistic water. I have to make a small space seem like it's an ocean.

Comment: Ok so I disabled surface tension and sheeting effects but everything keeps flying into the sky when it needs to just slide off of the submarine.

Comment: I have yet to fix the issue, sure it doesn't explode but the fluid now just seems like one big sheet, and it continues to rise up. I'm adjusting every setting I can that was related to this but none seem to stop the fluid from rising.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after testing things out between two computers I finally found the answer. FLIP Fluids does not have a time setting, the sub is just moving unrealistically fast and can't be edited, so the solution I found?

Make the water's speed at a similar rate to the sub. In spite of the fact I have no clue how to measure the sub's speed, the best render I got was when I set the domain's speed setting to 3. (This current image is taken of a new bake to see if I can get better results.)

Simply put: if an object is moving at an unrealistic speed in order to make the fluid react realistically with the FLIP Fluids addon you will need to adjust this speed setting to be similar to the speeds that objects passing through will be moving at.

[image]